# How to reverse engineer a binned column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have the following pandas DataFrame in which `col1` is binned (that binning is the result of a pandas binning):

```
d = {'col1': ['(-99999.0, -99998.0)', '(-99998.0, 1.0)','(1.0, 10.0)']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

The dataset looks like this:

```
                   col1
0  (-99999.0, -99998.0)
1       (-99998.0, 1.0)
2           (1.0, 10.0)
```

I need to reverse engineer the binned column so that I get a list called `myBinner` which looks like this:

```
myBinner = [-99998,1,10]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: The tuple is a string or a real tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.ravel` and `np.unique`:

```
import numpy as np

myBinner = np.unique(np.ravel(pd.eval(df['col1'])))[1:].tolist()
print(myBinner)

# Output
[-99998.0, 1.0, 10.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Or even shorter:

```
myBinner = [b[1] for b in pd.eval(df['col1'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also map `ast.literal_eval` and use list comprehension to filter:

```
import ast
myBinner = [x for _, x in map(ast.literal_eval, df['col1'])]
```

Output:

```
[-99998.0, 1.0, 10.0]
```